# How to wget a whole page with "Load more" button

Tags: bash, wget

I wonder if there is a way to download a whole page with a "Load more" button using wget as if the button was pressed as many times as possible.
[Here is](https://translate.yandex.ru/translate?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.silver.ru%2Fprogramms%2Fvzroslim-o-vzroslix%2FVipuskyprogrammy%2F&lang=ru-en) the page I would like to wget as you can see down there there is a button "Load more" button and if I just do

```
 wget http://www.silver.ru/programms/vzroslim-o-vzroslix/Vipuskyprogrammy/
```

I receive the page as you can see it in a web browser (obviously). Maybe there is another tool to solve my task?

Answer (score 0):

I've found that the "More button" is a link to "pageN_2". So wgetting "address?PAGEN_2" solves my issue.